# using moment js utc offset to filter an array of objects

Tags: arrays, typescript, filter, momentjs

i have an array of timezones that looks as follows

```
{name: '(UTC) Coordinated Universal Time', offset: '00:00:00', id: 'UTC'}
{name: '(UTC+00:00) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London', offset: '00:00:00', id: 'GMT Standard Time'}
{name: '(UTC+03:00) Istanbul', offset: '03:00:00', id: 'Turkey Standard Time'}
{name: '(UTC+04:00) Astrakhan, Ulyanovsk', offset: '04:00:00', id: 'Astrakhan Standard Time'}
```

so i am trying to filter the above list to find the matching utc offset that i give it as follows

```
this.timezones.filter(x=> moment().utcOffset(x.offset).utcOffset() == '240')
```

so 240 minutes is "04:00:00" offset from the timezone array
so my expected output should be

```
{name: '(UTC+04:00) Astrakhan, Ulyanovsk', offset: '04:00:00', id: 'Astrakhan Standard Time'}
```

But it just returns an empty array cause it cant find it.
What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
let objects = [
  { name: "(UTC) Coordinated Universal Time", offset: "00:00:00", id: "UTC" },
  {
    name: "(UTC+00:00) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London",
    offset: "00:00:00",
    id: "GMT Standard Time",
  },
  {
    name: "(UTC+03:00) Istanbul",
    offset: "03:00:00",
    id: "Turkey Standard Time",
  },
  {
    name: "(UTC+04:00) Astrakhan, Ulyanovsk",
    offset: "04:00:00",
    id: "Astrakhan Standard Time",
  },
];
const filteredObjects = objects.filter((obj) => {
  const offsetInMinutes = moment.duration(obj.offset).asMinutes();
  return offsetInMinutes > moment().utcOffset();
});
```

The result is object with id `Astrakhan Standard Time`

Hope this helps

Comment: thank you,i used your method but i added it as objects.filter((x) => Moment.duration(x.offset).asMinutes() == moment().utcOffset());